# Will an Irish visa refusal letter state if you have a ban or not in the UK, if you forgot to disclose

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, ireland, lost-documents, visa-bans

I have been refused twice in the UK. I cannot find my 2nd refusal letter. All efforts to locate it proved abortive.

However, I was refused in Dublin once and one reason for the refusal was that I did not disclose that I had 2 refusals from the UK.

If it were a ban would they have stated it instead of stating it as refusal? Because I need to know if I have a ban in the UK or not.

Comment: Whether you are subject to an entry ban depends on the *reason* for the refusal. Two denials don’t necessarily mean a ban. However, if one of your UK applications was refused for deception, a subsequent application may attract an automatic refusal period of up to 10 years. The period starts from the date of the previous event in which the deception or submission of falsified documents or information was employed https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1020413/Suitability_immigration_breaches.pdf

Answer (score 5):

> if it were a ban would they have stated it instead of stating it as refusal

This is a refusal because you **failed to disclose** your UK Visa refusals to the Irish authority

Ireland and the UK share immigration data, which is how they've seen that

This is likely to be a straight up 5y ban (like you would have had in the UK), and this **really bad** for your history.

From Traveller's comment :

> Failing to disclose the UK refusals in the Irish visa application is fraud and almost certainly means a ban of up to 5 years

> cos I need to know if I have a ban in the uk or not

Even though immigration data is shared, Irish and UK visas are separate (except in edge cases not covered here). A Irish visa refusal will not give you a UK ban

You may have a UK ban for deception, but you'd have to ask the UK authorities for that

See this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/174529/118049) on how to ask them for your data

Comment: Failing to disclose the UK refusals in the Irish visa application is fraud and almost certainly means a ban of up to 5 years https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/great-britain/our-services/visas/visas-for-ireland/

Comment: Note: a "ban" is often a decision (legally speaking), so you will not get automatic ban in UK. But you may get a ban by showing at border or with next application (but on some cases), so with real people taking a decision. And after this things are tricky. In any case, having two direct bans from UK is probably more relevant.